# Ubuntu 16.04 works badly and has strange behaviour

Tags: 16.04, boot, desktop-environments, interface

So, I have no idea why, but one day I restarted my laptop and my ubuntu started to behave strangely, i cannot move any window, I have no interface on the left part of the screen, when I close my laptop and open it again, login interface is different. Also `no such device: 567A-5400 and hd1 cannot get C/H/S values` appear if I try to open FreeDOS. I have no clue what to do and I do not want to reinstall ubuntu, because there are a lot of files that are important and I did not have time to save them anywhere else. 
Please help.

[image: Desktop picture]

[image: Login picture]

Comment: In such cases I would try to reset the GUI and see if it recovers.  Press Alt-Ctrl-F1. You get to a text console. Login with username and password. Then type 'sudo service lightdm restart'. This closes all your open programs and restarts the desktop (save any open stuff first). It should restart the desktop and give you the normal login. You can close the teminal by presssing Alt-Ctrl-F1 and enter 'exit'. Note that this does not solve the underlying problem. Its just useful go get going again for sporadic issues.

Comment: hardware issue?

Comment: FWIW you can (1) back up your data without GUI access, e. g. from a console or a live system, and/or (2) reinstall Ubuntu without data loss in `/home` or other directories that are not part of Ubuntu itself (see [Reinstalling Ubuntu without formatting /home, as well as without any old config files?](/q/56051/175814)).